# Should we use UITableView when we have UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have worked with both UICollectionView and UITableView and its trivial to make UICollectionView look like table. What is more usage patterns are very similar, you don't have to learn a lot of new stuff to use it.

The question is are there any arguments for using UITableView and not UICollectionView? Or we can just switch to UICollectionView and forget about UITableView?

Comment: CollectionView doesn't have a tableHeaderView and tableFooterView properties, which makes adding search bar functionality a pretty tough task

Comment: There also edit mode and swipe to delete you get with UITableView that you'd otherwise have to implement yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think so.

For  example, if you want to have some stickies header, you've got to create a custom Layout for your `UICollectionView`, whereas, it's really easy with `UITableView`.

Moreover you have `plain` and `group`tableViews, which is really usefull.

In my own opinion, I would say sometimes it's better to mutualize and use a collectionView (if it's a tableview on iPhone and a collectionView on iPad for instance), but not everytime.